# Creating a shorten URL for products using Amazon advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I'm using Amazon's API to browse for some products and I would like to generate an affiliate link for some of them.

I know I can get a normal affiliate link from the `DetailPageURL` field in the response (and that I can create one manually following the affiliate link format) but I would like to find an automated way to create a *shorten* URL for a product that contains my tag.

2 technical notes:

- Shorten URLs are the ones Amazon provides that look like amzn.to/12345
- I know I create these manually via the associates panel, but I'm looking for a way to get them using an API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this can be done using bit.y's API, as every Amazon URL shortened by bit.ly will get the amzn.to/{unique_id} format.

Comment: As of March 2024 Bitly are massively restricting free plan use of their API. I am seeing a 99.9% decrease in my new short link monthly quota and the closest plan to the original free plan will cost me $5000 per month now for what was previously free (and I was using the free allocation to drive new customers to them!). So, unless you are making serious money from your amzn.to short links, the Bitly API is no longer a practical solution, sadly.

Comment: Anyone know of a way to do this in 2024 without paying for Bit.lys api? If Bit.ly is doing it there must be a way.